# Is there an Excel VBA code sample to measure machine performance?

Tags: excel, vba, performance-testing

I'm having 4 different machines (3 laptops, 1 workstation) and I want to measure their performance by running the same Excel VBA code in all of them, sequentially. I do not want to measure the code performance but compare the machine's performance.

Does anyone have a good VBA code sample to measure

- processor speed
- memory access
- disk access
- ...
  ?

(I know already how to measure the duration between two code points)

Comment: There are many programs designed for this already and written cross-platform.

Comment: Sure, Mike, thanks. I just wanted something I can handle and get my fingers on to customize it for myself.